# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray' in py-faster-rcnn

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, caffe

I am training a py-faster-rcnn following instructions from https://github.com/deboc/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/help/Readme.md
on a custom dataset.

However, I am getting the following error :

```
    Preparing training data...
    Process Process-1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 122, in train_rpn
    roidb, imdb = get_roidb(imdb_name)
  File "./train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 67, in get_roidb
    roidb = get_training_roidb(imdb)
  File "/home/Work/code/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 122, in get_training_roidb
    rdl_roidb.prepare_roidb(imdb)
  File "/home/Work/code/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/roi_data_layer/roidb.py", line 31, in prepare_roidb
    gt_overlaps = roidb[i]['gt_overlaps'].toarray()
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'toarray'
```

This is the code-snippet of roidb.py (line 31):

```
for i in xrange(len(imdb.image_index)):
    roidb[i]['image'] = imdb.image_path_at(i)
    roidb[i]['width'] = sizes[i][0]
    roidb[i]['height'] = sizes[i][1]
    # need gt_overlaps as a dense array for argmax
    gt_overlaps = roidb[i]['gt_overlaps'].toarray()
```

I am unable to find a way around this.

Comment: `.toarray()` is a method of a scipy *sparse* array (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).  Have you passed in a regular numpy array to a function that expects a sparse array somewhere?

Comment: I managed to bypass the error by doing some minor edits,  `gt_overlaps = roidb[i]['gt_overlaps']
`gt_overlaps = sp.sparse.csr_matrix(gt_overlaps).toarray(), but then I am not sure if the final results will be as expected.

Comment: First check what `gt_overlaps` is.  Is it `np.matrix`?  `np.ndarray`.  If you can edit the code to add this `sp.sparse...`, you can also edit it to remove the `toarray`.  That would be the simpler fix.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard implementation, `roidb[i]['gt_overlaps']` on the posted line is expected to be a sparse matrix. You probably forgot this when defining your own dataset ground truth reader because it's originally a numpy.ndarray which is later converted. Other workarounds are possible (and perhaps preferable depending on application) but if you want to remain as close to py-faster-rcnn as possible, just wrap the `gt_overlaps` key of each ground truth like `overlaps = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(overlaps)`, further reference can be found in the original dataset files (i.e. `lib/datasets/pascal_voc.py`).